# Calculating finite inverse limits of Abelian groups

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-groups, abelian-categories, limits-colimits

If we are given an infinite system of abelian groups $(\dots \xrightarrow{\varphi_2} A_2 \xrightarrow{\varphi_1} A_1 \xrightarrow{\varphi_0} A_0)$ then I know its inverse limit can be found by
$$\lim_{i\geq 0} A_i = \ker(id - \varphi):\prod_{i\geq 0}A_i \to \prod_{i\geq 0}A_i $$ where $(id - \varphi)(a_0,a_1,a_2,\dots) = (a_0 - \varphi_0(a_1),a_1 - \varphi_1(a_2),\dots)$.

Can this also be applied to finite sequences, in particular can the limit of $(A_n \xrightarrow{\varphi_{n-1}} \dots \xrightarrow{\varphi_1} A_1 \xrightarrow{\varphi_0} A_0)$ be calculated in the same way? As an example I am trying to find the limit of $\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{\cdot 3} \mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$ (which should be $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$).

Comment: The limit of this diagram is $\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$, with the identity map to the first copy and the $\cdot 3$ map to the second copy. Perhaps you really wanted to find the limit (the *equalizer*) of the diagram consisting of the *two* maps $\text{id},\cdot 3\colon \mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}\rightrightarrows \mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: In general, the limit of $A_n\to A_{n-1}\to \dots \to A_0$ is $A_n$.

Comment: yes, I should have said there are also identity morphisms for every $A_n$. I have a problem that wants me to calculate the limit of $\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{\cdot 3} \mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$ as $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, maybe I forgot to add some assumption?

Comment: Adding assumptions won't change the answer, but, as @Alex Kruckman pointed out, changing the diagram, by putting in the identity function between the two $\mathbb Z/8\mathbb Z$'s, can produce $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ as the limit.

Comment: @AndreasBlass how does one find $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ as a limit then?

Comment: For the diagram in question, with both the identity and $\times3$ from the left $\mathbb Z/8\mathbb Z$ to the right one, the limit is the equalizer of those two maps. Alternatively (but with more work), you can use the general construction of limits; that way you get $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb Z/8\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z/8\mathbb Z:x=y\text{ and }3x=y\}=\{(0,0),(4,4)\}$, which is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$.